# set batch size for a lazy loaded collection in spring-data-jpa

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to generate a CSV file containing a database export. Since the data can be quite big, I want to use lazy loading with a specific batch size, so that when I iterate through the collection returned by the DAO/Repository, I will only have a batch loaded at one point. I want this to be done automatically by the collection (e.g. otherwise I could just load page after page, using `Pageable` as a parameter).

Here is some code to hopefully make things clearer. My controller looks something like this:

```
public ModelAndView generateCsv(Status status) {
    //can return a large number of items.
    Collection<Item> items = itemRepository.findByStatus(status);

    return new ModelAndView("csv", "items", items);
}
```

As you can see, I'm passing that collection to the view (through the ModelAndView object), and the view will just iterate through it and generate the CSV.

I want the collection to know how to load the next batch internally, which is what a lazy loaded collection should generally do.

Is there a way to do this with Spring-data or just plain JPA?
I know of `ScrollableResults` from Hibernate, but I don't like it for two reasons: it's not JPA (I'd have to make my code depend on Hibernate), and it's not using collections API, thus I'd have to make my view know about ScrollableResults. At least if it would implement `Iterable`, that would have made it nicer, but it's not.

So what I'm looking for is a way to specify that a collection is to be lazy loaded, using a specific batch size. Maybe something like:

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM Item o WHERE o.status = ?1")
@Fetch(type = FetchType.LAZY, size = 100)
Page<Item> findByStatus(Item.Status status);
```

If something like this is not possible using Spring Data, do you know if it can be done with QueryDsl? The fact that QueryDsl repositories return Iterator objects makes me think it might lazy load those, though I can't find documentation on that.

Thanks,
Stef.